# Adding the total number of distinct customers to a cte table in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, count, distinct, recursive-query

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server` and am trying to achieve the following

| Date | Distinct Customers last 30Days |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 20000 |
| 2020-12-02 | 23000 |

What I am trying to get is that between `2020-11-01` and `2020-12-01` I had `20000` distinct customers.

I have created a cte table with the List of Dates as can be seen below:

```
WITH listdate AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2020-11-01' AS datetime) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    listdate   
  WHERE   DateValue + 1 < getdate()
)

SELECT  
    cast(DateValue as date) as DateValue

FROM    listdate d
```

Now I am trying to join the customer and usage table with the list of dates table, however, I am not getting the correct end result. The following is what I have tried doing:

```
WITH listdate AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2020-11-01' AS datetime) DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DateValue + 1
  FROM    listdate   
  WHERE   DateValue + 1 < getdate()
)

SELECT  
    cast(DateValue as date) as DateValue
    ,count(distinct case when m.CallDate between dateadd(dd,-30,cast(d.datevalue as date)) and cast(d.datevalue as date) then m.Customerid end) as Distinct_CID
    
FROM    listdate d

join Usage m on d.DateValue=m.CallDate


left join Customer c on c.CustomerID=m.Customer

where c.customertype = 'type A'

group by d.DateValue

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Can someone maybe suggest a different way of how to solve such a query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a lateral join to bring the count of distinct customers for the last 30 days:

```
with listdate as (
   select cast('20201101' as date) as datevalue
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, datevalue) from listdate where datevalue < cast(getdate() as date)
)
select ld.datevalue, x.cnt
from listdate ld
cross apply (
    select count(distinct c.customerid) as cnt
    from usage u
    inner join customer c on c.customerid = u.customerid
    where 
        c.customertype = 'type A' 
        and c.calldate >= dateadd(day, -29, datevalue)
        and c.calldate <  dateadd(day,   1, datevalue)
) x
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Note that I simplified the parts related to dates: this uses proper literal dates and date arithmetics in the recursive query; the `where` clause of the subquery implements what I understand as the last 30 days (today + the preceding 29 days), and properly handles the time portion of `calldate`, if any.

Comment: thank you for this however when trying to run this query i got the following error

` Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "datevalue" of recursive query "listdate".`

Comment: thank you so much it seems to be working however, it is still running and been a while so once done I will let you know :)